# Layout (HTML5 + CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm having a small issue with my code . I'm trying to code after a long time and forgot a few basics. I'm trying to create a simple html layout .

As you will also see in the pictures , i'm getting another issue where the page is slightly longer than i expected and its showing the slider to move up and down . I didn't want this unless the page content is longer than expected (wrap) .

The top will remain fixed all the time . the footer will move based on the length of the content or stay fixed at the bottom if the content(wrap) is small.

What i'm expecting:

[image: exp]

What i'm getting (without top):

[image: exp]

with top :

[image: exp2]

---

HTML layout :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>

        @include('layouts.includes.head')

        <link href="{{ asset('/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id ="top">

        <div>

        <div id = "wrap">

        </div>

        <footer>

        </footer>

    </body>




</html>
```

CSS :

```
html,body 
{
  height: 100%;
  background-color:red;
}

#top {
  height: 50px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto -50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  width:auto;
}

#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto -50px;
  background-color: blue;
  width:auto;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: I notices 2 issues, the `<div id="top>` doesn't close and also in the CSS you have for `#top` both `height:50px;` and `height:auto;`. If these issues are also in your code they might cause your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `code` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cge89ef4/)

- Header and footer would be fixed only the content would be scroll.
- If there is no content the layout will be fitted as per the window resolution.   the scroller would be disable till then.

Answer (score 2):

Fix the footer to the bottom of the page and give the wrap element a bottom margin of the height of the footer so the footer will never overlap the wrap div.

```
#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
  background-color: blue;
  width:auto;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z5sukeky/1/)**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color:grey;
    position:relative;
}
#top {
    height: 50px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: yellow;
    width:auto;
    position:fixed;
    display:block;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
    background-color: blue;
    width:auto;

}
footer {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: Aha , its working :) tho i'm still getting the slider to move up and down

Comment: dont you need scroll if there is no content?

Comment: Ah , i set the height for html,body to auto and it fixed the issue. I'm not sure if its the best way tho or will cause other issues down the line

Comment: There's a small issue with the demo . I tried adding a long content and it does not work as intended . 1 <br>
1 <br> 
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br> 
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br> 
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br> 
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br> 
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br> 
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br> 
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br> 
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br> 
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br> 
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br> 
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br> 
1 <br>
1 <br>
1 <br>